# Best method of accessing a child div inside a directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

alright so, I'm constantly running into this problem where I need to select/access a wrapping container between a parent directive and its child directive.

**pseudo code:**

```
<div parent-directive>
   <!-- selecting the viewport becomes hard.  making an extra directive seems weird -->
   <div class="wrapping-div">
      <div child-directive ng-repeat="page in pages" ></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I don't want to use jQuery for selecting `wrapping-div` by class. And creating a extra directive for`wrapping-div` element makes the templates so thin and it reads weird?  Lastly, using `element.children()` from `parent-directive` seems really fragile?

### **Question:**

**What is the preferred method of selecting a child element from a template of a directive?  Is there Any way to keep it angular w/o making every part a directive?**

For a better context, I'm making a basic carousel directive called `wa-carousel`.

**Main.html**
*`wa-carousel` is an sort-of API:*

```
<div wa-carousel class="wa-carousel"></div>
```

**wa.carousel.html**
*this template has a directive: `wa-pages`.*

```
<div class="wa-carousel-viewport">

    <ul class="transition-fast wa-page-collection" ng-style="carousel.pagedOffseter">
      <li wa-pages page="page" class="wa-pages" ng-repeat="page in carousel.pages"></li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

As you can see there are 2 wrappers that are only classes not directives `wa-carousel-viewport` and `wa-page-collection`.

**The `wa-page-collection` will be using ng-touch but I'd like to control it from wa-carousel link function but I'm forced to use `el.children().children()` which I dont like.**

**wa.carousel.js**

```
   link: function(scope, el, attrs){

        var viewport = el.children().children();

        $swipe.bind(viewport, {
              'start': function(coords) {}
        })
     }
```

**What is the prefered method of selecting `wa-page-collection` in angular?  Is it considered bad practice to do the manipulation inside of `wa-carousel`'s link function?  **

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `data-` attribute or similar on the element you want to specifically target. Then:

```
link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
    var viewport = angular.element(el[0].querySelector('[data-my-attr]'));

    $swipe.bind(viewport, {
        'start': function(coords) {}
    })
}
```

If using jQuery, you can shorten the selector to `var viewport = el.find('[data-my-attr]');`